# display the results of php script on wordpress header

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, header, parameter-passing

Hello i am trying to display the result of search in my homepage. I am running an internet radio website and i am trying to get this to work.

The users will use the search engine to find a song "John" for example: http://tir.fullerton.edu/search/searchv2.php

it will show all possible results.
Then once they find it they click on the hyperlink ("this Song").

Then it display the results.

i want to be able to display these results on our header homepage. 
http://tir.fullerton.edu/

Comment: OK, but what is your question?

Comment: I want to be able to pass my results to my homepage. and display them there, how can i do that?

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to code your app. We can fix your errors or help you with an algorithm, but we're not going to give you the full implementation of your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what is in the searchV2.php you should try and capture the onClick event from the song they choose and then store it as a PHP session.

```
$_SESSION['SongChoice'] = "This Song";
```

Then in your header you can retrieve the result of the click via the session variable. This session will be around until the site is closed or until you reset it via another song choice, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
    <?php echo $resultsString; ?>
</header>
```

Vague question... This should work though.

Comment: The question how to pass $resultsString for example to the header. and how to receive it from searchV2.php?

Comment: Maybe make the searchV2.php POST to your page. And on that page in the header, handle the POST by displaying whatever you want.

Comment: The problem is i can't pass it to my header file inside my wordpress them you know?

Comment: You can't edit your header in wordpress? Why not? If you really can't you can inject anything via javascript.